# Find lowest file size in a directory with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I need to find the smallest file size from a directory. What is the best way to do it with Laravel and to keep the code as minimal as possible?

I am using this code, but I am sure there is a better and more efficient way.

```php
$files = Storage::files("videos");

$files = Arr::where($files, function ($value, $key) {
    return Str::contains($value, 'string..') && Str::endsWith($value ,'.mp4');
}); // keep only certain files from videos directory in the files array

foreach ($files as $key => $file)
{
    $files[$key] = ['file' => $file, 'size' => Storage::size($file)]; 
}

$min = collect($files)->min('size'); // 1000000

// find file by size...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `sortBy` with a callback to sort the files based on file sizes. Something like this perhaps,

```
//after Arr::where
$fileWithSmallestSize = collect($files)->sortBy(function($file){
    return Storage::size($file);
})->first();
```

---

Another option is to reduce the collection.

```
//after Arr::where
$fileWithSmallestSize = collect($files)->reduce(function($smallestFile, $file){
    return ( Storage::size($file) < Storage::size($smallestFile) )? $file : $smallestFile;
}, $files[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep the smallest while you loop the files:

```php
$files = Storage::files("videos");

$files = Arr::where($files, function ($value, $key) {
    return Str::contains($value, 'string..') && Str::endsWith($value ,'.mp4');
}); // keep only certain files from videos directory in the files array

$minSize = PHP_INT_MAX;
$minFile = null;
foreach ($files as $key => $file)
{
    $size = Storage::size($file);
    if ($size < $minSize) {
      $minSize = $size;
      $minFile = $file;
    }
    $files[$key] = ['file' => $file, 'size' => $size]; 
    
}

// $minSize is the smallest size in the directory and $minFile is the file with the smallest size

// $minFile will be `null` if there are no files in the initial array, you should add a check for this possibility
```